# Firebase push notification is being sent to iPhone from console but showing the status is "failed"

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am working with Firebase push notification service in iOS development. I can send push notifications from Firebase console to iOS devices but the problem is the status in Firebase console for the push notification is showing `Failed`. I have included "Development Certificate" in Firebase but "Production Certificate" has not been included yet. I can't figure it out where the problem is. Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show the error you get

Comment: Verify your `sender id` may be it's mismatched.

Comment: i am new to ios development, can you please elaborate your answer that where exactly can i verify "sender id"? @Buntylm

Comment: I have updated my problem with screenshot, would you please check it out? @MosheEdri

Comment: No need to include production certificate in your case. It will be ok in with development only. Problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah! Problem might be somewhere else but i can't figure it out! @Roohul